# Scheduled Task using Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper

Tags: c#, .net, string, task, scheduled-tasks

I have done a lot of searching over the last few days in regards to Checking if a scheduled task exists, if so `<insert awesome here>`.  Basically I have an app that installs and uninstalls our software's scheduled tasks.  What I need to do now is have a checkbox be checked if the task is there and unchecked if it's not. There was a reference to using:

```
        ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks(server);
        string[] taskNames = st.GetTaskNames();
        List<string> jobs = new List<string>(taskNames);
```

which isn't working for me, it's stating that the ScheduledTasks namespace could not be found. I believe I have what I need installed. "using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen this ScheduledTasks within this wrapper.

The [TaskScheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) uses a service idiom and you need to have the context of a folder.

They have good examples in their [documentation](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Documentation), including one for [enumerating all tasks](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Documentation#enum).

If you want to find a particular task:

```
var t = taskService.GetTask(scheduledTaskName); 
bool taskExists = t!=null;
if(taskExists) DoYourThing();
```

if your tasks are within a folder, then use something like the following

```
var t = taskService.GetTask(taskFolder + "\\" + scheduledTaskName);
```

Comment: yes, I was looking at that, but it isn't specific on finding a specific task, verifying if it exists and if so then do a task. The above code just gives a list of all the tasks. Mind you I am kinda new to c# so I could be missing something.

Comment: thank you sir. it seems so simple after I look at it. It's appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answer by Dove (I don't have the rep to comment yet), you can also use the FindTask method for [TaskScheduler](http://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/), which allows you to neglect specifying the sub-folder with the name if you enable searching within sub-folders by passing "True" as the second parameter; for instance.

```
using ( TaskService sched = new TaskService() ) {
    var task = sched.FindTask( "UniqueTaskName", true );

    if ( task != null ) {
        ...
    }
}
```